# Why I'm getting Req.Req (Nested request) with this configuration in express?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

**EDIT: If you have the problem with nested requests or responses. Check the order of the params, or use express.router({margeParams: true}) option.**

My requests are being wrapped by another object request.

I have to access 'req.body' that way -> req.req.body
That is because my configuration?

I got an express server with this config:

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/api', routes);

server.listen(80);
```

this is routes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import webhooksRoutes from './controllers/Webhooks/webhooksRoutes.js';

const routes = express.Router();
routes.use('/webhooks', webhooksRoutes);
```

this is webhooksRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
const userRoutes = express.Router();

userRoutes.post('/orders', orderWebhooks);
```

this is orderWebhooks.js

```
const wirecardOrdersWebhooks = (res, req) => {
    // here the "real" request that come to the server is in res.res
    const realReq = req.req
}
```

Comment: express application middleware takes the first argument as req

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the first argument should be the req before the res;

```
const wirecardOrdersWebhooks = (req, res) => {
   // here the "real" request that come to the server is in res.res
   const realReq = req.body
}
```

Comment: omG, that was really the case. I coudn't see this becauses there is an "req" inside the "res"
LMFAO